# Performance counter average time every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, performance

### Using perfmon tool I'm trying to capture average time taken by a transaction every 5 minutes. The result that i'm getting seems to be wrong. can someone help me.

```
 // Caller`enter code here`
 if (!_perfCounterDefinition.IsRegistered)
 {
    CreateCounter("name");
 }

 // initialize perfomance counter

var averageTransactions = new PerformanceCounter(name, "Average Transactions", false);
var baseAverage = new PerformanceCounter(name, "Average Transactions Base", false);
//check if elapsed time is 5 min; initialized counters
if (_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > (5000*60))
{
    //counter reset
    baseAverage.RawValue = 0;
    averageTransactions.RawValue = 0;
    _stopwatch.Reset();
}
else
{
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    averageTransactions.IncrementBy(_stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    baseAverage.Increment();
}
//Helper
private static void CreateCounter(string name)
 {
            var averageTransactions = new CounterCreationData()
            {
                CounterName = "Average Transactions",
                CounterHelp = "Average Transactions",
                CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageTimer32
            };
            PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(name, name, PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, counterData);
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What is the actual output? Your code sample above is confusing. I think you have several different snippets, but they are put together in a single block. I have no sense of what's executing when. Please create a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and add it to your question, along with an explanation of what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Basically I want to know the average time transactions took every five minutes using perfmon