# Average value of a Performance Counter over a specific time

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I want to write a program, which returns the average value **over a specific time** of a Performance Counter.

How do I get an average value for those Performance Counters without waiting the 
a specific time? I would prefer a solution which doesn't block.

There is already a similar Question but without answers.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194921/performance-counter-average-time-every-5-minutes)

Comment: You want to get the value of a performance counter historically, you mean?

Comment: If the counter itself does not already provide an average (some do) then it is up to you to sample the counter periodically and calculate the average yourself.  Or leave it up to Perfmon.exe

Comment: @ChrisShain I want to get the Average of the last 5 or 10 minutes

Comment: In that case @HansPassant is correct, you'll need to do the sampling yourself over time. There is no built-in historical database of values.